# How to approximate the student-t CDF at a point without the hypergeometric function?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, t-distribution

Is there a way to closely approximate the CDF of a student-t distribution at a point $x$ **without involving the hypergeometric function**? For example, by using a series expansion, or expressing the CDF in terms of simpler functions?

The t-distribution can [be expressed in terms of a normal and chi-squared distributions:](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Studentst-Distribution.html)

$$t = \frac{X\sqrt{n}}{Y}$$

where $X$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$; $\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}$ has a chi-squared distribution. Maybe this expression can help simplify the t CDF?

I am trying to write an algorithm to compute the student-t CDF for any real number, so using the hypergeometric function will be extremely difficult. I am also trying to avoid integrating the PDF to get the CDF.

Comment: There are standard, efficient algorithms to compute this CDF.  They were worked out in the 60's through the 80's and published in TOMS (Transactions on Mathematical Software), typically in Fortran.  It's usually straightforward to port them to any numerically-oriented computing platform.  Series expansions (except around infinity for the tails) won't work for CDFs in general.  Numerical integration often does well, depending on how much accuracy you need, for what values you typically need high accuracy, and how you measure that accuracy.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169352/mathematically-how-are-the-critical-t-values-calculated/169437#169437 (including some useful comments)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Wikipedia article on the $t$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Related_distributions) helpfully informs us that

> If $X$ has a Student's t-distribution with degree of freedom $\nu$ then one can obtain a Beta distribution: $$\frac {\nu }{\nu +X^{2}}\sim \mathrm {B} \left({\frac {1}{2}},{\frac {\nu }{2}}\right).$$

Equivalently, $1-\nu/(\nu + X^2) = X^2/(\nu + X^2)$ has a $B\left(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ distribution.  This is referred to as a "symmetry relation" below.

Here is an implementation in a C-like language.

```
extern FLOAT tcum(FLOAT t, DEGREES m) {
    if (m == INFINITY) return zcum(t);
    assert(m > 0);

    if (t == 0.0) return 0.5;
    if (t < 0.0)  return 0.5 * (1.0 - inbet(t*t / (m + t*t), 1, m));
    else          return 0.5 * (1.0 + inbet(t*t / (m + t*t), 1, m));
}
```

(It falls back to the standard Normal CDF `zcum` for arbitrarily large $\nu$.)

A good implementation of the Beta cumulative distribution `inbet` is given in [Numerical Recipes](http://numerical.recipes/), where `inbet(x,a,b)` is the incomplete Beta function $I_x(a,b).$

Long ago I ported their Fortran version of the function to C (cleaning up a few problems along the way).  It wasn't too painful.  It's a continued fraction expansion.  *Numerical Recipes* remarks

> This continued fraction converges rapidly for $x\lt (a+1)/(a+b+2),$ taking in the worst case $O\left(\sqrt{\max(a,b)}\right)$ iterations.  But for $x \gt (a+1)/(a+b+2)$ we can just use the symmetry relation $I_x(a,b)=1-I_{1-x}(b,a)$ to obtain an equivalent computation where the continued fraction will also converge rapidly.

You can see this strategy in the extensively tested version below.  You don't need the details of the header (.h) files to port this.  You *do* need enough experience writing scientific software to know that you *must* test your port thoroughly and to know how to do the testing and debugging.  (Reproducing extensive tables of the function to perfect accuracy is one approach.  It helps to graph the results, too: that catches all kinds of erratic errors that can afflict numerical programs.)

```
/* 
 *  INBET.C
 *
 * The incomplete beta function with parameters a/2 and b/2, i.e.,
 * integral, 0 to x, of 
 *     pow(t,(FLOAT)a/2-1)*pow(1-t,(FLOAT)b/2-1),
 * divided by beta(a/2,b/2).
 * x must be >= 0, <= 1, a, b must be > 0.  
 */                       
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include "stats.h"

static FLOAT betacf(FLOAT a, FLOAT b, FLOAT x);
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

extern FLOAT inbet(FLOAT x, DEGREES a, DEGREES b) {
    FLOAT bt;

    assert((FLOAT)0.0<=x && x<=(FLOAT)1.0);
    if (x==0.0 || x==1.0) {
        bt = 0.0;
    } else {
        bt = exp( lngamma2(a+b)-lngamma2(a)-lngamma2(b) +
                  0.5 * (a*log(x) + b*log(1.0-x)) );
    }
    if (x < (a+2.0) / (a+b+4.0))
        return 2 * bt * betacf((FLOAT)a/2.0, (FLOAT)b/2.0, x) / a;
    else
        return 1.0 - 2 * bt * betacf((FLOAT)b/2.0, (FLOAT)a/2.0, 1.0-x) / b;
} /* inbet() */
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

FLOAT betacf(FLOAT a, FLOAT b, FLOAT x) {
    FLOAT am = 1.0,
          bm = 1.0,
          az = 1.0,
          qab = a+b,
          qap = a+1.0,
          qam = a-1.0,
          bz  = 1.0 - qab * x / qap;
    FLOAT em, tem, d, ap, bp, app, bpp, aold;
    long m=1;

    do {
        em = m; tem = em+em;
        d = em * (b-m) * x / ((qam+tem) * (a+tem));
        ap = az + d*am; bp = bz + d*bm;
        d = -(a+em) * (qab+em) * x / ((a+tem) * (qap+tem));
        app = ap + d*az; bpp = bp + d*bz;
        aold = az;
        am = ap/bpp; bm = bp/bpp; az = app/bpp;
        bz = 1.0;
    } while (fabs(az-aold) >= stat_eps * fabs(az) && m++ <= _stat_iter);

    if (m > _stat_iter)
        _stat_err = _ERR_STAT_EPS;

    return az;
} /* betacf() */
/* eof inbet.c */
```

Comment: great answer, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @whuber I feel like you skip a few steps going from the relationship of the t-distribution to beta and then to the C implementation. For instance, why is it $t*t / (m + t*t)$ instead of $m / (m + t * t)$?

Comment: @John I see what you mean.  It comes down to a simple fact which is clear from inspecting the Beta density function: when $X$ has a Beta$(a,b)$ distribution, $1-X$ has a Beta$(b,a)$ distribution.

Comment: @PyRsquared I think what this answer brushes over and what your original post didn't elaborate on is the need for "any Real value". Such language makes me think you are trying to some kind of automatic differentiation, in which case this solution might not get you what you need.

Comment: @bdeonovic It is difficult to see how any method of differentiation might be relevant to computing the CDF, especially since the OP expressly excludes integrating the PDF to obtain the CDF.

Comment: @whuber What is the lngamma2 function referring to? The C lgamma function or a square of its results?

Comment: @mwater That's the log gamma function: it's used to compute the Normalizing constant.